# GridLayout overlapping cells?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-gridlayout

For some reason, my `GridLayout` will occasionally overlap cells.

This happens when the number of `rows` or `columns` exceeds 2. For example:

-If my grid has 3 objects in it, each with a different `row number` ranging from 0-2, a `row span` of 1, and a `column number` of 0, only 2 `rows` will be displayed. 1 `row` will show as normal and 2 of the `rows` will be displayed as overlapping each other!

-If there are 5 objects, each with a different `row number` ranging from 0-4, a `row span` of 1, and a `column number` of 0, only 3 `rows` will be displayed! 1 of the `rows` will display as normal, 2 of the `rows` will display overlapping each other, and then the other 2 `rows` will display overlapping each other.

Here is a snippet of my code, simplified:

```
public void addToView(HorizontalScrollView masterView, ArrayList<Member> memberList) 
    GridLayout myGrid = new GridLayout(this);
    int wrap =  HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams(wrap, wrap);

    for(Member member: memberList){

        //consistent with logs, no overlap
        final int rowSpan = member.getSpan();

        //consistent with logs, no overlap
        final int column = member.getColumn();

        //consistent with logs, no overlap
        final int row= member.getRow();

        //each of these are equal to 4 DIP
        final int marginsHor = /*excluded for simplicity*/;
        final int marginsVert = /*excluded for simplicity*/;

        //equal to (75 - (2 * horizontal margin)) in DIP
        final int width = /*excluded for simplicity*/;

        //equal to ((75*row span) - (2 * vertical margin)) in DIP
        final int height = /*excluded for simplicity*/;

        ImageButton container = new ImageButton(this);
        container.setPadding(marginsHor, marginsVert, marginsHor, marginsVert);
        container.setImageDrawable(member.getImage());
        container.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

        GridLayout.Spec rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row, row + rowSpan);
        GridLayout.Spec columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(column, column+1);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(rowSpec, columnSpec);
        layoutParams.height = height;
        layoutParams.width = width;
        layoutParams.setMargins(marginsHor, marginsVert, marginsHor, marginsVert);

        grid.addView(container, layoutParams);
    }

    masterView.addView(myGrid, layoutParams);
}
```

The view they are added to:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/addToMe">
        </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. NO CLUE why this fixed it, but I guess you're not supposed to use the other `spec` with a span of 1.

```
    GridLayout.Spec rowSpec;
    if(span == 1){
        rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row);
    }
    else{
        rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row, row + span);
    }
    GridLayout.Spec columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(column);
```